# Run Google sheets script on multiple tabs, affecting different rows on each tab

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, javascript

I am trying to run my script across multiple tabs on my Google sheet, to affect a range of different rows on each (multiple drop down functions)

How do I get it to affect specific sheets, and not them all? I have tried all sorts, but it puts everything out of whack.

For example, Sheet 1 needs a multiple drop down option for rows 4,5,6 and Sheet 4 needs the option for rows 16,17,18

Code below for reference:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var oldValue;
var newValue;
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
if(activeCell.getColumn() == 4,5,6,7,9,10,11,16,17,18 && ss.getActiveSheet().getName()=="Sheet 1") {
newValue=e.value;
oldValue=e.oldValue;
if(!e.value) {
activeCell.setValue("");
}
else {
if (!e.oldValue) {
activeCell.setValue(newValue);
}
else {
activeCell.setValue(oldValue+', '+newValue);
}
}
}
}
```

I am very new at coding, so really lost here

Comment: Hi. I'm a Web Applications Stack Exchange Community Moderator (volunteer) and a Stack Overflow user with experience on the topics related to this site. I migrated the question from Web Applications to Stack Overflow because the underlying problem concerns programming rather than using Google Sheets and Google Apps Scripts as web applications / end-user. Programming is a topic that "belongs" to Stack Overflow, not to Web Applications. Best regards.

Comment: Try using [getSheetByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getsheetbynamename) to do what you'd like with Sheet 1 and Sheet 4.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: Use JavaScript control and return statements.

The most common command sequence control statement in JavaScript is the `if` statement.

As a `onEdit`, due to being a reserved name used for the simple trigger that is fired every time that user does an edit, the only way to avoid the changes that your code does to be done on specific sheets is by using a control statement. You can use it to make the execution engine skip a section of your code or exit earlier utilizing the return statement, among other options.

The code in the question has some errors. I suggest you spend some time learning the basics of JavaScript on a proper place or using the appropriate resources to do so. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info.